# excel vba, for each workbook, load it and run a function defined in that workbook

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am writing an Excel VBA program that loads
the name and for each, load the corresponding
Excel workbook, execute the function "Button2_click" and then print the first worksheet
in the workbook.

I got all to work except running the
subroutine of the specific name within that
spreadsheet.
On the indicated line, I get
Run time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method

(As you might guess, each of these spreadsheets have a button that invokes `Button2_Click`
I simply want to automate loading each
workbook, clicking the button, and hitting
the print button.)

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
N = 8
Dim F As String
Dim wb As Workbook

For i = 6 To N
    ChDir "P:\101_"
    CV = Cells(i, 1).Value
    MsgBox "loading " & CV
        
    F = "P:\101_\" & CV & ".xlsm"
    MsgBox "loading |" & F & "|"
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(F)
    MsgBox " wb is |" & wb.Name & "|"
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Run "'" & wb.Name & "'!Button2_Click"   ' indicated line
    
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close (False)
    Set wb = Nothing
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're encountering is potentially due to the way you're trying to run `Button2_Click` subroutine. The `ActiveWorkbook.Run` method doesn't exist, which is why you might be getting an error.

You should try the `Application.Run` method to execute the subroutine. Here's how you can modify your code to fix the error:

```vb
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
N = 8
Dim F As String
Dim wb As Workbook

For i = 6 To N
    ChDir "P:\101_"
    CV = Cells(i, 1).Value
    MsgBox "loading " & CV
        
    F = "P:\101_\" & CV & ".xlsm"
    MsgBox "loading |" & F & "|"
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(F)
    MsgBox " wb is |" & wb.Name & "|"
    
    ' Use Application.Run to execute the subroutine
    Application.Run "'" & wb.Name & "'!Button2_Click"
    
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close (False)
    Set wb = Nothing
Next i
    
End Sub
```

With `Application.Run`, you're telling Excel to run the `Button2_Click` subroutine within the specified workbook. This should hopefully the error you're encountering.